# Linking failing when trying to call C functions from Unity

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

Trying to call a custom Objective C function form C#. However it keeps saying that it is not defined.

Whenever i try to build in Xcode it says that _ShowDropIn is undefined?

The function is defined as:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 //#import "BraintreeCore.h"



 #import <BraintreeCore.h>
 #import <BraintreeDropIn.h>


 @interface BrainTreeHandler : UIViewController
  #ifdef _cplusplus
  extern "C"{
      -(void)ShowDropIn:(const char *)clientTokenOrTokenizationKey;
  }
  #endif


  @end

  @implementation BrainTreeHandler

  #ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C"
  {


  -(void)ShowDropIn:(const char *)clientTokenOrTokenizationKey{

      BTDropInRequest *request = [[BTDropInRequest alloc] init];
      BTDropInController *dropIn = [[BTDropInController alloc]initWithAuthorization:clientTokenOrTokenizationKey request:request      
 handler:^(BTDropInController * _Nonnull controller, BTDropInResult *      _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {

          if (error != nil) {
              NSLog(@"ERROR");
          } else if (result.cancelled) {
              NSLog(@"CANCELLED");
          } else {
              // Use the BTDropInResult properties to update your UI
              // result.paymentOptionType
              // result.paymentMethod
              // result.paymentIcon
              // result.paymentDescription
          }
      }];
      [self presentViewController:dropIn animated:YES completion:nil];

  }
  #endif

  @end
```

Calling from Unity C# code

```
  [DllImport("__Internal")]
     private static extern void ShowDropIn(string s);

      void ShowBrainTree(){
      //clientToke is a string
        ShowDropIn(clientToken);
      }
```

This function should call the brain tree UI but right now just gives me an undefined error.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `C`? It is clearly about `Objective-C`, which is an entirely different language.

Comment: I don't think this makes sense at all. I am not an Objective-C guru, but isn't `-` meaning that this is an *instance* method, and then you've got a static method without any namespacing in C#...?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that first time ever trying to code Objective-C. Fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

So, at the top of each **C** header file (after the include guards), we have

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

and at the bottom, we write

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

you should not include your `func` define between `__cplusplus`

```
-(void)ShowDropIn:(const char *)clientTokenOrTokenizationKey
```